# current user and FBA roles in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, forms-authentication

I have logged FBA user in Sharepoint 2010 with FBA and need know what FBA roles it has.
**SPContext.Current.Web.AllRolesForCurrentUser** returns non FBA roles.
How can I get FBA roles for current FBA user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found solution for my question, it is very simple:

```
// Gets a value indicating whether the currently logged-on user is in the specified role
System.Web.Security.Roles.IsUserInRole("Provider");
```